# iOS - How to remove previous view after loading a new view?

Tags: iphone, ios, multiview

I am practicing multiview but having a small problem.

When my new view gets loaded, I can still see previous view.

How to make previos view invisible??

Here is my code :-

```
- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender 
{
    RedClass *red = [[RedClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"RedClass" bundle:nil];
    self.redClass = red;
    [red release];
    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:redClass.view];        
}
```

and here is a screenshot :-

[image]

And when I uncomment `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` then my red view is not even getting loaded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  color of your red view may be transparant .

so please check it in your nib file of redclass. also check alpha for your red view it must be 1.

You can not remove your first view here. because it may be loaded at window or other controller. so if you are adding view2 in view 1 and removing view1 then view2  automatically get removed ,because it is already in view1 . so you can not write  `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: is there a way by which i can make previous view invisible rather then remove? because if the transparent color is the problem then there must be some solution as people could use transparent color in the apps.

Comment: means hv u used transparant color? make self.view.alpha  = 0 and red.view.alpha - 1 and test , i m not sure but check it once..

Comment: No i did not used a transparent color but a lighter red. and view.alpha not working. it made my view complete white. But if i changed color to blue or green then my previous view isn't visible. What is this all about? why light red is working as a transparent red?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare view variable in .h file. and alloc it in `viewDidLoad` and don't release it there. Whenever you want to add view use, `[self.view addSubview:red];` and when you want to remove you can use `[red removeFromSuperview];`

Answer (score 1):

`[self.view removeFromSuperview]` removes the uiview which you is displayed.
So you need to call removefromsuperview for previously loaded view and call addsubview for new one.